# Regex in Cake model validation

Tags: regex, validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I need to validate social security number in the format XXXXXX-XXXX (each X represents a number; 6 digits followed by hyphen followed by 4 digits)

Here is what I am using for validation.

```
'rule' => array('custom', '/[0-9]{6}\-[0-9]{4}/')
```

However this is not working as expected. It's accepting any length of numbers both before and after the hyphen but it should only validate patterns mentioned below.

```
123456-7898
675443-8765
```

It should not match,

```
12345677-876
1233-976655
123455-987
12345-08765 and so on ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include anchors for the start and end of the string in your pattern

```
/^[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{4}$/
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be working. Don't we need to escape the hyphen?

Comment: @Vikram the hyphen is only a meta character inside of character classes